# Perform task by using finger tracking in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game in mixed reality. I want to track fingers in a particular motion so that I can fire an attack on the opponent in the real world.
I need help on how to do this. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Not done myself, but my approach would be to use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) and try to detect the finger and then analyse its movement.

It's not an easy task but could work under certain conditions.